# How do I specify conditional geom_errorbars based on whether the number is positive or negative?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, errorbar

I have positive and negative values that I'd like to put in a bar graph using `ggplot2`. I'd like to display just the upper standard errors when the bar/value is positive, but the lower standard errors when the bar/value is negative. Below is reproducible code to calculate the means, variance, barplots:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  Flyway = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "M", "M", "M", "M", "C", "C", "C", "C", "P", "P", "P", "P"),
  Year = c("2020", "2021", "2020", "2021", "2020", "2021", "2020", "2021", "2020", "2021", "2020", "2021", "2020", "2021", "2020", "2021"),
  North.South = c(182, 187, 318, 163, 6, 33, -41, -25, -70, -144, 226, 50, 121, 66, 225, -300)
)
  
dat %>%
    group_by(Flyway, Year) %>%
    summarise(mean.dist = mean(North.South, na.rm = TRUE),
              sd.dist = sd(North.South, na.rm = TRUE),
              n.dist = n()) %>%
    mutate(se.dist = sd.dist / sqrt(n.dist),
           se.upper = mean.dist + se.dist,
           se.lower = mean.dist - se.dist,
           lower.ci.dist = mean.dist - qt(1 - (0.05 / 2), n.dist - 1) * se.dist,
           upper.ci.dist = mean.dist + qt(1 - (0.05 / 2), n.dist - 1) * se.dist) %>%
    ggplot(aes(fill = Year, y = mean.dist, x = Flyway), color="black") + 
    geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity", color = "black") +
    geom_errorbar(position = position_dodge(0.9), stat = "identity", color = "black",
                  width = 0.1,
                  aes(y = mean.dist,
                      ymin = mean.dist,
                      ymax = mean.dist + se.upper
                  )) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed", color = "black") +
    scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE, option = "E") +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 20),
          legend.title = element_text(size = 16),                       
          legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
          axis.title = element_text(size = 16),
          axis.text = element_text(size = 12),
          axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 25, hjust = 1),
          element_line(color = "black"))+
    theme(legend.position="bottom") +
    xlab("Flyway")+
    ylab("North-South Distance Moved (km)")
```

[image]
Notice that Flyway `C`, `M`, and `P` have negative values. However, I can't figure out how to conditionally plot the lower standard errors (i.e., `se.lower`) for just those bars. Any help would be much appreciated! -nm

Comment: Is this right `ymin = mean.dist `?

Comment: Yes, this is correct because I only want upper SEs when the bar/number is positive. And only lower SEs when the number is negative. But I don't want both because several would overlap 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `ifelse` in your calculation of the `ymin` and `ymax` values in the `geom_errorbar`.  Keep everything else the same, but change that part to

```
geom_errorbar(position = position_dodge(0.9), stat = "identity", color = "black",
            width = 0.1,
            aes(y = mean.dist,
                ymin = mean.dist + ifelse(mean.dist < 0, se.lower, 0),
                ymax = mean.dist + ifelse(mean.dist > 0, se.upper, 0)
            )) +
```

This creates the plot below.
[image: screenshot]

However, it also looks to me as though your `se.upper` and `se.lower` calculations are wrong.  You seem to be calculating "mean + s.e." instead of just "s.e." as the name suggests.  If that's the case, you should use

```
geom_errorbar(position = position_dodge(0.9), stat = "identity", color = "black",
            width = 0.1,
            aes(y = mean.dist,
                ymin = ifelse(mean.dist < 0, se.lower, mean.dist),
                ymax = ifelse(mean.dist > 0, se.upper, mean.dist)
            )) +
```

or maybe better, fix those calculations so the value matches the name.